# Finding the largest duplicate array member in C

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates, member

I need to sort an array for the largest number that occurs at least twice in it.
The array is one line but imported from a .txt file so the dimensions are 1xn.

I thought maybe do it like this, any ways this is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char buff[1024];
FILE *f = fopen("f.txt", "r");
fgets(buff, 1024, f);
printf("\nBufer: %s\n", buff);
fclose(f);

int i;
char *p;
char *array[1];
i = 0;
p = strtok (buff,"/");
while (p != NULL)
{
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, "/");
}
for (i=0;i<1; ++i)
printf("Array: %s\n", array[i]);
```

Now how can I sort the **char array** to remove any members that occur only once. And then how do I find the largest of what's left?

Comment: As a first step, write a complete program that sorts the numbers.  When you get that working, then you can figure out how to find the largest duplicate.

Comment: please indent the code

Comment: ALWAYS check the result of fopen()!

Comment: what sort of no.s are they, ints, floats? you may have to investigate stdlib.h atoi atof type functions.. or maybe ditch fgets/strtok in favour of fscanf